# Odd behavior with xsl templates

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a piece of XML I have generated via an xquery, and I'm attempting to apply my xsl stylesheet to it.  I know the stylesheet works with the xml files I used to build the query, but I'm not sure why it doesn't work with my generated xml:

I have the following piece of xml in one of the source documents:

```
<zone n="EETS.QD.4">
<line n="l.1">
    <orig><hi>O</hi> alle ye <gap quantity="8" unit="chars" reason="illegible"
    />s of ierusaleem<note place="bottom" anchored="true"
        xml:id="explanatory">The “l” in “ierusaleem” in the final word is
        determined from context.</note></orig>
</line>
```

In the xquery-generated document, this is combined with lines from other documents to get the following:

```
<list xml:id="compare">
            <item>
                <orig>London, British Library Harley 2251: <ref target=".html">O alle ye doughtres · of Jerusalem</ref>
                </orig>
            </item>
            <item>
                <orig>London, British Library Harley 2255: <ref target=".html">
                    <hi rend="blue_pilcrow">¶</hi>O alle ye douħtren of <hi rend="underline">ierusaleem</hi>
                </ref>
                </orig>
            </item>
            <item>
                <orig>Long Melford, Holy Trinity Church Clopton Chantry Chapel: <ref target=".html">
                    <hi>O</hi> alle ye <gap quantity="8" unit="chars" reason="illegible"/>s of ierusaleem<note place="bottom" anchored="true" xml:id="explanatory">The “l” in “ierusaleem” in the final word is
                        determined from context.</note>
                </ref>
                </orig>
            </item>
            <item>
                <orig>Cambridge, Jesus College Q.G.8: <ref target=".html">
                    <hi>A</hi>ll the <hi rend="underline">doughtren </hi>of <hi rend="underline">Ierusalem</hi> .</ref>
                </orig>
            </item>
            <item>
                <orig>Oxford, Bodleian Library Laud 683: <ref target=".html">O alle ẏe douhtren of jerusaleem</ref>
                </orig>
            </item>
        </list>
```

In both cases the following template is applied:

```
<xsl:template match="tei:orig/tei:gap">
    <xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
    <xsl:variable name="max" select="@quantity"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="1 to $max">
        <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

In the standard document, it displays what I want correctly:

```
O alle ye [........]s of ierusaleem
```

But when applied to the generated document, I get the following:

```
O alle ye s of ierusaleem
```

It's obvious it's not finding the child nodes, but I'm not sure why since the template is working from the orig tag.

A secondary problem I have is that I can't get the note element to suppress either via xquery or xslt, but I suspect it's related to this issue with gap.  Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: In the XQuery generated doc, `gap` isn't a child of `orig`; it's a child of `ref`.

Comment: I don't see any `gap` elements...

Comment: That's exactly it.  I feel like a total idiot for not catching that.  Thanks Michael!

Comment: Consider either deleting your question, or self-answer your question for reference so that future generations can learn from this. But since it turned out to be a trivial oversight, I'd suggest deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: the answer to this question is not mine, and was given in the comments. For completeness and to consider the question answered, I am adding it here, as the question is not deletable anymore.*

> *I don't see any `gap` elements...[^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32383534/odd-behavior-with-xsl-templates/32401932#comment52641310_32383534)*

By [Michael Kay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/415448/michael-kay) and

> *In the XQuery generated doc, `gap` isn't a child of `orig`; it's a child of `ref`. [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32383534/odd-behavior-with-xsl-templates/32401932#comment52638341_32383534)*

by [Daniel Haley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/317052/daniel-haley) both point to the same issue, causing the code of the OP to fail. In other words, the XPath did not select anything because the path to the element was not correct.